# Not able to install ggplot

Tags: testing, ggplot2, statistics, package, rattle

I get the following error when installing ggplot:

> package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(j <-
>   i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):  there is
>   no package called ‘pkgconfig’

What am I missing?

Comment: How to overcome this error message?

Comment: try `install.packages("pkconfig")`, then `install.packages("ggplot2")`

Answer (score 0):

```
install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies=TRUE)
```

Comment: Although this may be a correct answer. One line of code isn't very useful without an explanation of what and how it solves the original question. Please provide details to your answer.